# Define point locations in relation to slope

Tags: qgis, slope, geolocation, aspect

I have a dataset of settlements that I would like to put in relation with slope and aspect layers that I have made to see if there is a preferred altitude or direction (facing north or south, etc.) that might have influenced the location of the settlements. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS SE! Please be sure to take the [tour] to understand what is expected of a high-quality, focused question. In general, asking a question here is the last thing to do after you've made an honest attempt at solving the problem and have encountered a problem. It is not a place to begin a discussion or ask "how do I" kinds of questions.
Can you elaborate as to what you've already attempted in solving this problem, and what problems you've encountered?

Answer (score 2):

Answers here will vary based on what software you are using, what formats the data are in etc. I can give a "in theory" answer that should start to help conceptually.

For exmaple, if we assume the aspect and gradient layers you have made are raster based (pixels) getting these values into the point layer table should be very easy. In a software like QGIS, you would bring the point shape layer in with the two other rasters and then simply use the SAGA '[Add raster values to point](http://pvanb.wordpress.com/2014/07/01/sampling-raster-values-at-point-locations-in-qgis-an-update/)' tool. This will allow you to (as you may have guessed) add the raster values of aspect and gradient to your point layer (which are the huts) and then you can start analyzing these to look for patterns.

If your data is in a different format or you are using different tools, please specify that and I can see if I can modify my answer to be more specific to your case.